# Pulling elements from an SVG file apart

Tags: svg, word-cloud

I am using [http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/) to generate a word cloud in SVG format. Unfortunately the generator deletes all `\` characters, which is bad since I want to 'wordcloudize' a list of TeX primitives.

I'd like to increase the spacing between the elements of the SVG automatically to be able to add `\` manually in the SVG file. Is there any SVG-transformation which moves the elements away from the center while leaving the size of the elements as they are?

Comment: May help to put the final svg on a jsfiddle for people to play with, highlighting the problem. I'm wondering if you could have a translate followed by a scale (so the scale centre of origin is the centre of the cloud), and then if necessary scale the other elements down (adjusting font size or scaling?).

Answer (score 0):

The much simpler solution is to download the page and its scripts to your local machine.  Open the local page and check that it still works.

Then open the cloud.js file and comment out the line:

```
word = word.replace(punctuation, "");
```

I think that should work.